# Is it wrong to duplicate content from elsewhere on the internet?

Tags: discussion

I came across [this thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?744955-RESOLVED-trying-to-get-the-smallest-number-from-an-array-always-return-quot-0-quot) when attempting to fix problems of my own and found it very relevant to my problem.

I would like to know what is wrong with his solution for my own edification.

Is there anything wrong with me reposting his question to SO? or is this frowned upon? is giving a link pointing to the source enough?

Comment: As long as you link to the original source when duplicating code, you should always be in the clear. It might not even be required, but I'd say common decency dictates you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its is perfectly OK to post question on SO, since you have the problem and the other thread doesn't gives you clear answer. there is more chance  that you'll find someone that can help you, and that is the purpose of SO site. Focus on your problem, where you are stuck..

As one of the goal of SE sites is make the **problem solving easy**